# easiest separator in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I reviewed many library implements Separated list:
SuperSaiyanScrollView, HeaderListView, StickyListHeaders, android-section-list etc.
but they all have me unnecessary functionality. I need a regular list, with conventional separators. just ordinary separators between each group an item

```
separator
  item
  item
  item
separator
  item
  item
  ....
```

I do not need to stick to the separator top edge of the screen. Give the simplest library for this. or better yet, how to do it without libraries?

Comment: How about ExpandableListView? You can disable the expand/collapse functionality if you don't need it. And this is standard Android, not a third party library

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: Another option is to use a normal ListView. Your items object can contain a variable like isGroup and groupName for example, but then you need to manually return the right View in the Adapter getView method (one for groups, another for the items), you would also need to disable the clicking on the groups and that kind of stuff.

Comment: how to make it always has been expand? Can I edit the node view?

Answer (score 0):

So far I think, if you simply need to display separator and items i.e kind of groups-child hierrachy,then instead of using libraries,you should go for [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). This is native in android and you can easily customize groups(header/separator) and child Views. Moreover, if you want your List to be always expanded, you can use this method of ExpandableListView

```
yourExpandableListView.expandGroup(index);// index of group which you want to remain expanded.
```

Also if you don't want your group item to be clicked you can simply override this method

```
yourExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and return true in that

For Tutorial on ExpandableListView,you can refer this

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/